# Mondodb driver: codec for case object

Tags: mongodb, scala, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to persist case class with ADT propertie. Let's say:

```
sealed trait Status
case object Ok
case object Fail

case class Operation(_id: String, status: Status).
```

I tried [official approach](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/getting-started/quick-tour-case-classes/) but it's work only for case classes and fails for case object. Also tried to define custom codec with Status-String mapping. But this approach also broken.

```
class StatusCodec extends Codec[Status]{
  override def encode(writer: BsonWriter, value: Status, encoderContext: EncoderContext): Unit = {
    writer.writeString(value.toString)
  }

  override def getEncoderClass: Class[Status] = classOf[Status]

  override def decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): Status = {
        reader.readString match{
         case "Ok" => Ok
         case "Fail" => Fail
        }
      }
    }
```

Finally found related feature request in mongo [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SCALA-343)
The only workaround I found is use plain Document type.

Are there more options?